# React hook callback from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this child component called `TodoList`

```
const TodoItem = ({ checked, children }) => 
   (<TouchableOpacity 
      style={{ backgroundColor: checked && 'red'}}>
      {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const TodoList = props => {
  const {
    options = [],
    onSelect,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  const [selectedOptionIndex, setSelectedOptionIndex] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onSelect(options[selectedOptionIndex]);
  }, [onSelect, options, selectedOptionIndex]);

  const renderItem = (o, index) => {
    return (
      <TodoItem
        key={o + index}
        onPress={() => setSelectedOptionIndex(index)}
        checked={index === selectedOptionIndex}>
        {index === selectedOptionIndex && <Tick />}
        <Text>{o}</Text>
      </TodoItem>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View {...rest}>{options.map(renderItem)}</View>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

And I have a parent component called `Container`

```
export default function() {
  const [item, setItem] = setState(null);
  return (
    <Screen>
      <TodoList options={[1,2,3]} onSelect={(i) => setItem(i)} />
    </Screen>
  )
}
```

I want to have a callback from child component to parent component using `onSelect` whenever a `TodoItem` is selected. However, whenever the `onSelect` is called, my `TodoList` re-renders and my `selectedOptionIndex` is reset. Hence, my `checked` flag will only change to `true` briefly before resetting to `false`.

If I remove the `onSelect` callback, it works fine. But I need to `setState` for both child and parent. How do I do that?

Comment: What does `ToDoItem` look like? Would you mind creating a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or a [CodePen](https://codepen.io) or even a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.io) that reproduces this issue? It would just be easier to help you that way.

Comment: It looks like you are doing something in 'setItem(i)' that alters the state of the 'Container' component, which causes it to re-render.

Comment: You may have to prevent default, what element gets rendered?

Comment: so how does `Container` really use `item` state variable? by now it seems to be ignored, but I believe in your app it's passed back to `ToDoList`. do you use it as a `key` prop by chance?

Comment: I have this CodeSandBox which demo what I want
https://codesandbox.io/embed/twilight-dawn-jbm6f?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why thats happening for you, most likely because the container's state is changing, causing everything to rerender.

Something like this should help you out, though.

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const ToDoItem = ({checked, label, onChange, style}) => {
  const handleChange = event => onChange(event);
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleChange}/>
      {label}
    </div>
  );
}


const ToDoList = ({items, onChosen}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  
  const handleChange = item => event => {
    let s = [...selected];
    s.includes(item) ? s.splice(s.indexOf(item), 1) : s.push(item);
    setSelected(s);
    onChosen(s);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {items && items.map(i => {
        let s = selected.includes(i);
        return (
          <ToDoItem 
            key={i} 
            label={i} 
            onChange={handleChange(i)} 
            checked={s}
            style={{textDecoration: s ? 'line-through' : ''}}/>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [chosen, setChosen] = useState();
  const handleChosen = choices => {
    setChosen(choices);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ToDoList items={["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]} onChosen={handleChosen} />
      {chosen && chosen.length > 0 && <pre>Chosen: {JSON.stringify(chosen,null,2)}</pre>}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my top-level component `Screen` is causing this re-render. In my `Screen` functional component, I have this piece of code before the `return`

```
  const Content = scroll
    ? contentProps => {
        const { style: contentContainerStyle } = contentProps;
        return (
          <ScrollView {...contentContainerStyle}>
            {contentProps.children}
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
    : View;

  return (
    <Content>{children}</Content>
  )
```

And it somehow (not sure why) causes the children to re-render every time my state changes.
I fixed it by removing the function and have it simply returning a `View`

```
  const Content = scroll ? ScrollView : View;
```

Comment: oh, yes, it's how reconciliation work. During update phase it choose to update or re-create child based on `key` first and type(constructor function or tagname for predefined elements) second(once `key` is equal or absent at all). Since you're declaring `Content` as anonymous function inline you're getting brand new constructor on each render. So React will recreate this element(meaning all its state is reset to initial values) any time it re-renders hierarchy.